# Why does the Bode plot in LTspice disagree with my command calculation?

Tags: ltspice, bode-plot, frequency-response

I am trying to use LTspice to plot Bode plot for frequency response. I used command to get the gain at the 1kHz first. In the error log it turns out that it is 47.3dB.

[image]

When I used small signal AC to analyze the gain(V_out_stage/V_in_stage) in the Bode plot at 1kHz just only about 20dB. (Same circuit)

[image]

What caused the difference?

Below is the complete circuit:

[image]

Comment: No you can use any voltage as a reference, you set it in the AC parameters of the voltage source

Comment: Why do poeple complicate themselves with using anything other than `AC 1` as the source's value? An `.AC` analysis is only performed on a *linearized* circuit, which is why, not only it won't blow up when using `AC 1k` but, the outputs can safelt and reliably report 100 dB or more for a unity input. Not to mention the hassle of having to divide to get a proper reference. `.AC` is not `.TRAN`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using PP on an .AC is it doesn't know where in the frequency range to take the measurement.

Here is an example of how to find the voltage of an AC measurement at a certain frequency

```
.meas AC V(Vout) FIND V(Vout) AT 1kHz
```

So for the first measurement

```
.meas Vin AC V(Vin_stage) FIND V(Vin_stage) AT 1kHz
.meas Vout AC V(Vout_stage) FIND V(Vout_stage) AT 1kHz
.meas Gain param Vout/Vin
```

Comment: I've changed the command to yours, the gain at 1kHz at error log become 53dB, but it is still different from 20dB in the Bode plot.

Comment: Can you update the question? Also what does trans @1khz look like?

Comment: Thanks, I think I've solved the problem. The Vout at 1kHz becomes around 20dB and the Vin becomes -33dB. Then gain becomes 20-(-33)=53dB.

Comment: Weren't you dividing though? with the .meas?